# PNG versioning - aka login.png?ver=23514

Tags: css, image

In my wordpress installation, in the CSS file for the login screen, the background image is specified like so:

```
.login h1 a {
    background-image:url('../images/wordpress-logo.png?ver=20120216');
    ....
}
```

So there is a query string after the png, but how is it read? In the images folder, the png is simply called `wordpress-logo.png`. The weird thing is, if I replace it, it is not shown.

Obviously I could just remove the versioning in the CSS file, but I'm curious how that works. So, how does png versioning work and how can I use it? Thanks.

Comment: That's probably just a cache-buster

Comment: I think you're right... I couldn't get my replacement to show up in chrome until I changed the "version" number. Care to enter that in as an answer? And I will select it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a cache-buster.

If you change the image, you can change the date in the cache-buster to force the browser to re-download it.

Web servers ignore query strings on static files.